# nginx rewriting static asset to different path

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a main app located at `root`: `/app/web`.

Then another app within a subdirectory - `/app/web/second`.

Pages are located in `/app/web/second/<env>/page`.

Assets are located in `/app/web/second/<env>/css` and `/app/web/second/<env>/js`.

`<env>` can be `dev` (staging) or `dist` (production), so will change depending on the instance.

In code the assets are referenced as e.g. `/second/css/style.css`. I need these requests to be rewritten to their proper filesystem location e.g `/app/web/second/dev/css/style.css`

Here's what I have to manipulate requests on `dev`:

```
  root  /app/web;

  location /rsvp {
    alias  /rsvp/dev;
    rewrite  ^/rsvp/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ $document_root/page/title.php?id=$1 last;
    rewrite  ^/rsvp/(.+)\.(css|js)$ $document_root/$1/$2 last;
  }
```

The page rewrite works fine. The script log shows:

```
GET /second/foobar HTTP/1.1 200 > /app/web/second/dev/page/title.php
```

The asset rewrites are completely different. The `root` isn't prepended and the `alias` is duplicated. Script log:

```
GET /second/css/style.css HTTP/1.1 404 > /second/dev/second/dev/css/style/css
GET /second/js/script.js HTTP/1.1 404 > /second/dev/second/dev/js/script/js
```

This is a legacy codebase so standing it up is a priority over refactoring it to a better structure.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$document_root` in the `rewrite` statement. The `rewrite` statement changes one URL into another URL. Nginx then uses `root` to convert a URL into a local pathname. See [the `root` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root).

Answer (score 0):

I assume `rsvp` and `second` mean the same thing in your question.

I would try the following configuration:

```
location /rsvp {
    root /rsvp/dev;

    location ~ /rsvp/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ {
        try_files /title.php?id=$1 =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/rsvp/(.+)\.(css|js)$ {
        try_files /$1$2 =404;
    }
}
```

The pattern is to configure common `root` for `try_files`, and then use regular expressions in `location` directives to capture relevant parts to form the filename part in `try_files`.